# Is there a two-dimensional 'map' equivalent in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, functional-programming

I'm trying to generate a matrix by applying a function to all combinations of elements of two vectors -- something like this:

```
A(i,j) = fun(X(i), Y(j));
```

Best solution I've found is to loop over all i and j, but I know that's bad style in Matlab. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically what [MESHGRID](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html) is for. It replicates vectors of values into meshes, and a function can then be applied to those meshed points. You can usually take advantage of [matrix and element-wise array operations](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/arithmeticoperators.html) to avoid using a for loop to perform certain computations on the resulting meshes. Here's an example:

```
>> X = 1:4;  %# A sample X vector
>> Y = 1:5;  %# A sample Y vector
>> [xMat,yMat] = meshgrid(X,Y);  %# Create 2-D meshes from the vectors X and Y
>> fun = @(x,y) x.^y;   %# A sample function, which raises each element of x to
                        %#   the corresponding element of y power
>> A = fun(xMat,yMat)   %# Apply the function to compute A

A =

           1           2           3           4
           1           4           9          16
           1           8          27          64
           1          16          81         256
           1          32         243        1024
```

Notice that the first input to [MESHGRID](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/meshgrid.html) (i.e. `X`) is treated as running along the columns, while the second input (i.e. `Y`) is treated as running down the rows. This is generally desired if `X` and `Y` represent Cartesian coordinates and the matrix `A` is going to be plotted as a 3-D surface or mesh. However, you could also use the function [NDGRID](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ndgrid.html) if you want this behavior "flipped". Here's the same example with [NDGRID](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ndgrid.html):

```
>> [xMat,yMat] = ndgrid(X,Y);
>> A = fun(xMat,yMat)

A =

           1           1           1           1           1
           2           4           8          16          32
           3           9          27          81         243
           4          16          64         256        1024
```

Notice that `A` is now a 4-by-5 matrix instead of a 5-by-4 matrix.

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Thanks!